# Dynamic graphing using python?

Tags: python, graph, matplotlib

I know similar questions have been asked already but I was wondering what is the most *efficient* way to dynamically plot in Python? I've read about using gnu, matplotlib, etc. but I'm tasked with putting out 6 plots that are all dynamically updating at the same time so I'm looking for efficiency (granted there will be a dedicated machine for the graphing operations).

Comment: you can make a fair amount of progress using blit.  How fast do you want to go?

Comment: and is this a gui based? web based?  What sort of data are you plotting?

Comment: It would be web based, I was thinking that I might try implementing django as well but I'm not sure quite how I'd go about doing this. It doesn't need to be altogether too fast, I mean right now I have it moving at something like...5 frames per second just as an estimate.

Comment: Please include those details in your question.

Answer (score 1):

I've found [Graphite](http://graphite.wikidot.com) to be among the most efficient realtime graphing packages available for python.